# Continuity of Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

I do not understand 2 things about this Proposition.

1) Why for the first identity, we have increasing sequence of events, and for the second one we have a decreasing sequence. Is there some intuitive explanation for this? Maybe a graphical? I tried graphing it but then could not connect the logic between the identity and the picture.

2) I do not understand at all what does the limit of P(An) is for n -->inf. Is it the sum of these probabilities? Is it the union/intersection convergence to some probability? What exactly does this mean? I understand what the first part of the identity is but no clue for the second, and can't seem to find a decent explanation.

I have the proof written, but I can't understand it fully because these things are slightly confusing me

Comment: Well, for the first part:  try examples.  Suppose you take a decreasing sequence for the first one...does the claim still hold?

Comment: For the second: For each $n$, $P(A_n)$ is a number, so the limit is just the ordinary limit of a sequence of numbers.

Comment: @lulu so the limit doesn't have to go until inf? It goes until n?  I think I now understand, since if for first,  n=3 and it's a decreasing sequence, then the union would not be able to equal the smallest event( A3). It would equal A1. Okay I think i get it. So the same reasoning would be for the second one.

Comment: What? Of course the limit "goes to $\infty$".  But this is just an ordinary limit of a sequence of numbers, like $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n$, say.

Comment: Work concrete examples.  That's the best way to understand abstract definitions.

Comment: ok, but what would P( $A_\infty$ )be equal to then?

Comment: There is no $A_{\infty}$.  If you have a sequence of real  numbers, $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, do you know what $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ means?

Comment: yes, a1, a2,a3,a4,...

Comment: Yes, that's the sequence, but I asked if you knew what the limit meant.

Comment: Yes, it means that the sequence goes on and on, not stopping at any number. For example lim n-->1 for 1/n would mean n goes very close to 1 but doesn't reach it. (sorry if im explaining myself in a non-mathematical  way)

Comment: That's really not what the limit means..  I think that's the source of your confusion.  Review the ordinary definition of a limit of a sequence of real numbers.  In the case of the probability claim, all you have to do is to define $a_n=P(A_n)$ to understand the definition in terms of the ordinary one.

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks btw

Comment: FYI: You can re-state these results for _any_ sequence of events $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (without the need for increasing or decreasing events) as \begin{align} P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i] &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[\cup_{i=1}^nA_i]\\ P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i] &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[\cap_{i=1}^n A_i]\end{align}  In the special case when $A_i\subseteq A_{i+1}$ for all $i$ we have $A_n = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$.  In the special case when $A_i \supseteq A_{i+1}$ for all $i$ we have $A_n = \cap_{i=1}^n A_i$.

Comment: @Michael actually this is what I wanted to clarify(the two identities which you restated).Thanks